# ajax call from pure javascript not returning response from remote php file(no jQuery)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, http-headers, cross-domain

I am using pure javascript to make an ajax call to a PHP file which is residing in the **remote server**. But it is not returning the response.

The page which is making the ajax call is in my **localhost**.

Here is the ajax call code:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            if(xmlhttp.responseText == 1){
                document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = "Update Successfull";
            }
        }
    }
    //https://flo2go-airteliptv.rhcloud.com
    xmlhttp.open("POST",'https://xyz.com/purchasereturn.php',true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("setflag=1");
```

The PHP code on the remote server is this:

```
<?php
header('content-type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8');
    $purchasevalue = 0;
    while($purchasevalue != 1){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM purchase WHERE purchase_id = 1";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $purchasevalue = $row['purchase_flag'];
        }
    }
    //$purchasevalue = "{purchase:$purchasevalue}";
    echo $purchasevalue;
?>
```

How can I get the response ? Please help.

Comment: Have you tried using your browsers dev tools to see what's happening?

Comment: Also why set the content-type to js?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you ask `if(xmlhttp.responseText == 1){` the xmlhttp.responseText is the actual response and I see you returning json so it will never return 1 so it will never get inside the if

Comment: not sending - retrieving ! the javascript code `document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = "Update Successfull";` will never occur because the responseText is not 1 - it's a json

Comment: Ok - what is the value $purchasevalue - try to see in the inspector what are you getting back from the server (maybe there are errors with your db or something...)

Comment: no there are no errors in the DB because I executed the PHP file directly and it returned 1. By the way the $purchasevalue will be 1.

Comment: So there is nothing wrong with your code now - I tested it locally at my server - my php echo's 1 - and it's working fine. if not for you please publish the entire cycle include html